# Self reference for assertions while unittesting

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest, self-reference

First, assume the following directory structure of a Python package titled `mypackage`, which follows the instructions of the guide [How To Package Your Python Code](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io):

```
mypackage/
mypackage/mypackage/
mypackage/mypackage/__init__.py
mypackage/mypackage/a_function.py
mypackage/scripts/
mypackage/scripts/a_script.py
mypackage/tests/
mypackage/tests/a_function_test.py
mypackage/misc/
mypackage/misc/input.txt
# mypackage/misc/actual_output.txt  ## Not yet generated!
mypackage/misc/expected_output.txt
mypackage/setup.py
```

Second, assume that the script `a_script.py` imports `a_function.py`, reads the file `input.txt`, manipulates the content of `input.txt` and saves the latter as `actual_output.txt` into `mypackage/misc/`.

Third, assume that the unittest module `mypackage/misc/` contains a test function to compare `expected_output.txt` to `actual_output.txt` via `self.assertMultiLineEqual(expected, actual)`.

Finally, assume that I would like to run the unittest module via `python2 setup.py test`.

How do I specify the location of `actual_output.txt` and `expected_output.txt` in `a_function_test.py` without hardcoding their absolute filepaths (and, hence, preventing any transferability of my package)?

**Consideration:**

I can theoretically hardcode the within-package path to each of the two input files. However, how does the Python interpreter know where to look for `mypackage` if it is not yet installed to `site-packages`? I had the following idea, but it fails as `mypackage` is not yet known:

```
base_path = os.path.split(inspect.getfile(mypackage))[0]
within_path = mypackage/misc/
expected = open(base_path + within_path + expected_output.txt).read()
actual = open(base_path + within_path + actual_output.txt).read()
self.assertMultiLineEqual(expected, actual)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `a_script.py` you can get to the main `mypackage` like so:

```
mypackage_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

or:

```
mypackage_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__package__))
```

then, the other paths can be built, since you know the name of the subpackages:

```
misc_dir = os.path.join(mypackage_dir, 'misc')
tests_dir = os.path.join(mypackage_dir, 'tests')
```

Comment: Thank you, but that `os.path.abspath(__package__)` fails with `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'`.

Comment: Are your directories python packages? Is there an `__init__.py` contained in them. Else, it may not work

Comment: I had only placed an `__init__.py` into `mypackage/mypackage/` (see edited question). Which ones of the other subpackages should I place an  `__init__.py` into?

Comment: To turn all directories containing `.py` files into packages and subpackages, you should add an `__init__.py`. So the main `mypackage` should also have an  `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Okay, I placed an empty `__init__.py` file into `/mypackage/`. However, I still receive an error message as shown hereafter [Note: markdown renders the word _package_ bold if I precede and follow it by two underscores, hence the strange spelling]: `base_path = os.path.abspath(_ _package_ _)`   `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 360, in abspath   if not isabs(path):   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 54, in isabs   return s.startswith('/')   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'`

Comment: Go with the `__file__` approach then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112129/discussion-between-moses-koledoye-and-michael-gruenstaeudl).